# How to install http_v2_module in NGINX?

Tags: nginx, http2

I want to install HTTP/2 in my site. I haven't http_v2_module in NGINX. How to install it?

This is result of `nginx -V`

```
nginx version: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --without-http_browser_module --without-http_geo_module --without-http_limit_req_module --without-http_limit_conn_module --without-http_memcached_module --without-http_referer_module --without-http_scgi_module --without-http_split_clients_module --without-http_ssi_module --without-http_userid_module --without-http_uwsgi_module --add-module=/build/nginx-pzhfc2/nginx-1.10.0/debian/modules/nginx-echo
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after NGINX version upgraded.